# Give an example of a two variable function where you cannot reverse the order of integration.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We can always interchange order of integration of continuous multivariate functions.  But is there an example of a function (not continuous) for which you cannot interchange order of integration? In particular I'd like an example with finite limits of integration.

Comment: Lots of books give such examples. See Rudin's RCA, for example.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Can give page number for Rudin's RCA?

Comment: My copy of the book is not an international edition so I cannot give the  exact page number. In the chapter on 'Integration on Product Spaces' there is a section on 'Counterexamples'.